# Showing pop-up window after pressing a notification

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

I made this app, it gives notification to user between a certain time. Notification shows just a string, one big sentence. (Notification is like all the messages are shown, at top-left of the screen)

So some strings are too long to read, when I click to notif. it re-opens the application. What I want is, is to show the string in a pop-up window. I think it is better than to open app again.

So how can I do this, or any other solutions? Like string goes left to right so user can read, like broadcast sign.

Thanks!

This is my manifest.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/elma"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <service android:name=".Service_class" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.package.Acilis"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.package.Class1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.package.Class2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.package.Class3"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about dressing up an activity as a dialog?

add

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

to your android manifest to see an example.  You can customize it to look like any popup you would like.

Comment: This didn't help. I think I need a specific notification class for that? I applied this to mainactivity, it dialoged all app.

Comment: it will just convert that specific activity to a dialog theme.  Maybe try creating a new activity with dialog theme and then have the notification open that activity instead of your main activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to dress the activity as a dialog, you can visit the [Notification design guide](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) on developer.android.com and take a look on the Expanded Layouts.
I think it will be better to your case.